# MediaPlayer: баг Android 10

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Перешел с API 28 на 29.
Есть код, для воспроизведения случайной музыки с телефона.

```
mus.setDataSource(songsList.get(rnd.nextInt(songsList.size())));
mus.prepare();
mus.start();
```

На 28 все работает хорошо, на 29 ничего не происходит.
Это происходит только а Андроид 10 на реальных (3 шт) и виртуальном телефонах (на низких версиях все ОК).
В логах не вижу никаких ошибок.

Интересный и **ВАЖНЫЙ** факт:
баг происходит, если устанавливать приложение с нуля. если оно уже было установлено на API 28 и обновить его на 29 - все будет работать хорошо.

Нигде ничего не сохраняю, ни кэширую. Получаю список песен только при нажатии на кнопку.
Чтение разрешено - вижу в логах весь список песен.
Разницы между путем к песне нету (пробовал как `Path` так и `Uri`)

Comment: Скорее всего это связано с изменениями в получении доступа к файловой системе на новых версиях ОС. Скорее всего, если поковырять тот код, в котором вы получаете пути к файлам, то можно будет найти проблемное место и/или ошибку. Также, скорее всего, просто обойти эту проблему не выйдет - скорее всего придётся у юзера явно запрашивать разрешение на доступ к файлам на девайсе. Скорее всего отсутствие проблемы при обновлении вызвано попыткой минимизировать сложности миграции. Коли так, то у вас должно опять перестать работать после обновления и последующей очистки данных из системных настроек аппа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалось с "чтением" файлов.
Того, что я писал `"Получаю список песен только при нажатии на кнопку"` оказалось мало.
Для Android 10 в Манифесте теперь недостаточно обычных

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Надо добавить еще строчку в блоке  `<application>`

```
     <application>
            android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
....
```

Если targetSDK < 29 - этой проблемы не возникает. Но вот если =>29, то надо добавлять этот кусок.

Comment: это костыль и на android 11+ (sdk 30+) уже работать не будет

Comment: @IR42 а костыль "от чего" и "для чего"?